# integral of a function in the real line.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$\int_{a}^{b}{\left(\frac{1}{x^2} +1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx}$$ for $0<a<b$.

I don't know how to compute this at all.

Can you give me a hint please?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575946/indefinite-intergral-of-int-sqrt-x2-a2-over-x-dx/576504#576504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let x = tan(u), and 1 + (tan(u))^2 = (sec(u))^2, and dx = (sec(u))^2*du, and you can take it from there.

Comment: I did like that. but I can't find the answer...

Comment: I did it thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

The integral $$\int_{a}^{b}{\left(\frac{1}{x^2} +1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx}$$ when $0<a<b$ can be written as $$\int_{a}^{b}{\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}dx}=\int_a^bx^{-1}\sqrt{1+x^2}dx$$ Now set $1+x^2=t^2$.